# How to do formula conditioning in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Something like this
        
IFS(I2="Smart/TNT",  SUM(C2+3), I2="Globe/TM", SUM(C2+2))
or is there a better way?
Example: I want the cell to look up a condition                                                                               

If Smart/TNT = +3 to the amount located before that cell and                                                           
if Globe/TM = +2 and                                                                                                                                       
if etc = +10                                                          
                                                                                                                                                   
If amount is located at C2 the output would be located at D2          
If the value in C2 is 10 and it checks I2 what condition it satisfies and like                                        
if it is Smart/TNT then the output will be 13  since 10+3=13 and so on...                                           
if it is Globe/TM the output should be 12                              
if it is etc then the output will be 20
```

[Click this for the image of the sheet I am telling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RptiF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the formula as shown in the picture?

[image]

Formula in **D2**:

```
=C2+VLOOKUP(I2,$L$2:$M$4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes but how about if I don't have the table at the right side like I want to put the value to be added inside the formula

Comment: Also another situation wherein I want every Smart/TNT is added 3 but it has exceptions like if its Angel May then the value added would be different like example other people if they buy 50 then they pay 53 but if it is Angel May the price will be 3+7 which is 10 that makes 50 to 60 instead 53

Comment: IF or IFS function will work for you.

Comment: Yes but I do not know how to properly use it I tried it but it wont work

Comment: can you perhaps give me the formula of those two situations I have given above? please? thank youu

Comment: Here is a sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RJgH.png  Formula in **C2**: =IFS(I2="Smart/TNT",  C2+3, I2="Globe/TM", C2+2,I2="Sun",C2+10)

Comment: What's wrong with this how to fix it? @lee https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnszR.png

Comment: What version of Excel did you use? Can you use IFS function in Excel? This function only available for Office 2019 or Microsoft 365 subscription.

Comment: You can change the formula to: =IF(I2="Smart/TNT",C2+3,IF(I2="Globe/TM",C2+2,IF(I2="Sun",C2+10,"")))

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2007

Comment: This worked thank you very much
=IF(I2="Smart/TNT",C2+3,IF(I2="Globe/TM",C2+2,IF(I2="Sun",C2+10,"")))

Comment: Hey @Healer, if the answer worked for you, consider upvoting and marking it as the correct answer :)